# Getting CSS tab to be open by default

Tags: html, css

So, I'm trying to redesign how our product descriptions look on eBay,  but am having trouble figuring out how to get the first tab to be open automatically.  With how its setup now,  it's you have to click on Product Description (tab) to display its contents.  I can't seem to figure out where or what I have to add to have it automatically open.

Can anyone offer any assistance?

Thanks!!

```css
<style type="text/css">.css-tabs {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  /* This is only if you want the tab items at the center */
}

.css-tabs ul.menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  /* Change this to block or inline for non-center alignment */
}

.css-tabs ul.menu>li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

.css-tabs ul.menu li>a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #808080;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 4px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.css-tabs ul.menu li>div {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  margin: -1px 0 0 0;
  z-index: -1;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0;
}

.css-tabs ul.menu li>div>p {
  border: 0px solid #808080;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
}

.css-tabs ul.menu li>a:focus {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

.css-tabs ul.menu li:target>a {
  cursor: default;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

.css-tabs ul.menu li:target>div {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
  <title>Ebay Template</title>
  </style>
</head>

<body>









  <center>

    <p><img src="https://centralvalleycomputerparts.com/product_images/uploaded_images/location.png" width="100%" height="166" /></p>
    <table style="height: 651px; width: 100%;" border=0>
      <tbody>
        <tr style="height: 493px;">
          <td style="width: 18.9401%; height: 493px;">
            <table style="height: 485px;" width="152">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td style="width: 142px; text-align: right;"><strong>
<font size = 5>
Categories<font></strong></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="width: 142px; text-align: right;">
                    <hr>All Products
                    <hr>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="width: 142px; text-align: right;">Add-On Cards
                    <hr>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="width: 142px; text-align: right;">Accessories
                    <hr>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="width: 142px; text-align: right;">Cables
                    <hr>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="width: 142px; text-align: right;">Cisco
                    <hr>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="width: 142px; text-align: right;">Desktops/Laptops/Servers
                    <hr>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="width: 142px; text-align: right;">Electronics
                    <hr>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="width: 142px; text-align: right;">Hard Drives
                    <hr>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="width: 142px; text-align: right;">Heat Sinks
                    <hr>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="width: 142px; text-align: right;">Keyboards
                    <hr>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="width: 142px; text-align: right;">Memory / RAM
                    <hr>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="width: 142px; text-align: right;">Motherboards
                    <hr>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="width: 142px; text-align: right;">Power Supplies
                    <hr>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="width: 142px; text-align: right;">Processors
                    <hr>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="width: 142px; text-align: right;">Server Components
                    <hr>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="width: 142px; text-align: right;">SSDs
                    <hr>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="width: 142px; text-align: right;">Video Cards
                    <hr>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="width: 142px; text-align: right;">Other
                    <hr>
                  </td>
                </tr>



              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
          <td style="width: 78.9688%; height: 493px;">
            <p>
              <!-- it goes here -->

              <form method="get" action="http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html" target="_blank">
                <table style="margin:auto; font-family:arial; text-align:left; background:#ddd; border:1px solid #888; border-radius:.25em">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <input type="hidden" name="_ssn" value="central_valley_computer_parts_inc">
                        <input type="hidden" name="_sop" value="12">
                        <input type="text" name="_nkw" value="">
                        <input type="submit" value="Search">
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="LH_TitleDesc" value="1">
                        <small>include description</small>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </form>
              <div id="tab2" class="css-tabs">
                <ul class="menu">
                  <li id="item-1">
                    <a href="#item-1">
                      <font face="Helvetica" size=5>Product Description</font>
                    </a>
                    <div>
                      <p>
                        <!-- ******************************-->
                        <!-- Product Description goes here -->
                        <!-- ******************************-->
                        <center>



                          <img src="https://cdn8.bigcommerce.com/s-bxaxkh/product_images/uploaded_images/product-description.png?t=1532892462&_ga=2.208211035.830779260.1532892407-1079763816.1532576134">


                        </center>
                        <!-- ******************************-->
                        <!-- Product Description Ends here -->
                        <!-- ******************************-->
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                  <li id="item-2">
                    <a href="#item-2">
                      <font face="Helvetica" size=5>About Us</font>
                    </a>
                    <div>
                      <p>Central Valley Computer Parts, Inc. has been in business since 2010. What started as a home business and hobby 7 years ago has since grown into a full-blown business supporting 10 team members! We operate out of a warehouse in Ripon,
                        California and strive to provide the best customer service we can. We hope to serve you for many years to come!</p>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                  <li id="item-3">
                    <a href="#item-3">
                      <font face="Helvetica" size=5>Return Policy</font>
                    </a>
                    <div>
                      <p>
                        <!-- ******************************-->
                        <!-- Start Return Policy -->
                        <!-- ******************************-->
                        <img src="https://cdn6.bigcommerce.com/s-bxaxkh/product_images/uploaded_images/terms2-a.jpg?t=1504814802&_ga=2.109104901.102196424.1504814843-1761240196.1503617547">




                        <!-- ******************************-->
                        <!-- end return policy -->
                        <!-- ******************************-->
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                  <li id="item-4" title="click for Tab 4">
                    <a href="#item-4">
                      <font face="Helvetica" size=5>Tab 4</font>
                    </a>
                    <div>
                      <p>Tab Content 4</p>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <p>
                <p>
                  &nbsp
                  <p>
                    <p>
                      &nbsp
                      <p>
                        <p>
                          &nbsp
                          <p>
                            <p>
                              &nbsp
                              <p>
                                <p>
                                  &nbsp
                                  <p>
                                    <p>
                                      &nbsp
                                      <p>
                                        <p>
                                          &nbsp
                                          <p>
                                            <p>
                                              &nbsp
                                              <p>
                                                <p>
                                                  &nbsp
                                                  <p>
                                                    <p>
                                                      &nbsp
                                                      <p>
                                                        <p>
                                                          &nbsp
                                                          <p>
                                                            <p>
                                                              &nbsp
                                                              <p>
                                                                <p>
                                                                  &nbsp
                                                                  <p>
                                                                    <p>
                                                                      <p>
                                                                        &nbsp
                                                                        <p>
                                                                          <p>
                                                                            &nbsp
                                                                            <p>
                                                                              <p>
                                                                                &nbsp
                                                                                <p>
                                                                                  <p>
                                                                                    &nbsp
                                                                                    <p>
                                                                                      &nbsp
                                                                                      <p>
                                                                                        <p>
                                                                                          &nbsp
                                                                                          <p>
                                                                                            <p>
                                                                                              &nbsp

                                                                                            </p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>







</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please reduce your code to the minimum required to reproduce the problem, please see: [MCVE]. There is a **lot** of unnecessary code there. Unrelated to you problem, but worth  mentioning, the `center` and `font` tags are deprecated and no longer should be used. You should also avoid using `tables` for markup.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with javascript like following.

```
location.href=location.href+"#item-1";

http://jsbin.com/hogasozucu/edit?html,output
```

Comment: Is there a way do it without JS?

Answer (score 0):

of course it is possible only with css3 like following

```
.css-tabs ul.menu li:first-child>a { cursor: default; border-bottom: 1px solid #fff; } 
.css-tabs ul.menu li:first-child>div { display: block; }

please try it on jsbin.com/mazazomamu/edit?css,output
```

Comment: this does sort of work, but once you open other tabs it goes over. :D im trying to make modifications to the code now but if you come up with anything to fix that i'd much appreciate it :D